# How to register hibernate FunctionContributor in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, function, hibernate

I have implemented the interface, add sql function using 'registerPattern(...)', but I can't find how to register FunctionContributor in Spring boot.

```
public class MyContributor implements FunctionContributor {
    public void contributeFunctions(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
    
     ...

    functionContributions
        .getFunctionRegistry()
        .registerPattern(...);
    }
}
```

Can this be done using application prop file?

Comment: it is based on Java SPI, just place `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor` file with `com.tld.etc... MyContributor` contents into resources folder